# Expressões regulares com Java Patterns

Tags: java, regex

Preciso fazer um exercício da faculdade que é o seguinte:
Validar com os expressões regulares qualquer palavra que contenha exatamente dois caracteres 'a' e dois caracteres 'b' ou mais.
Fiz a seguinte expressão na classe `Pattern`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a{2}b{2,}");
```

Esse `Pattern` só valida expressões que comecem com dois caracteres 'a' e posteriormente dois ou mais 'b'. Porém o exercício exige que os dois caracteres à possam estar em qualquer lugar na frase e não necessariamente no começo, assim como os caracteres 'b'.
Como faço essa expressão regular

Comment: `.*a{2}b{2,}.*` vê se serve.

Comment: Não funcionou, pois não validou a string "babba", e nesse exercicio, essa string seria válida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido. Utilizei o seguinte Pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(bbb*ab*ab*)|(babb*ab*)|(baabb*)|(ababb*)|(aabbb*)|(abbb*ab*)");
```

Comment: O seu `Pattern` falha em alguns casos como `"bcdbaa"` ou `"ababd"`. Dê uma olhada na minha [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/186231/64560).

Answer (score 1):

O que você deseja é uma verificação.

A regra diz, que contenha :

- 2 caracteres `a`
- 2 caracteres `b` ou mais

Note que no `b` a parte "ou mais" é irrelevante pois se tiver 2 `b` já é valido.

#### Resolução

`(a.*){2}b.*b|(b.*){2}a.*a|(a.*b|b.*a){2}`

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/VeAkh4/1).

#### Explicação

- `(a.*){2}b.*b` busca por sentenças que tenha `a` seguido de `a`, apos `b` seguido de `b`.
- `(b.*){2}a.*a` busca por sentenças que tenha `b` seguido de `b`, apos `a` seguido de `a`.
- `(a.*b|b.*a){2}` busca `a` seguido de `b` ou `b` seguido de `a`.

Comment: Mas caso a string seja `ccabcab` ele não identifica

Answer (score 1):

#### Utilize um [lookahead positivo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?=padrão)
```

Um lookahead permite verificar se o grupo pode ser encontrado iniciando-se na posição que se encontra, mas sem capturar nem avançar na leitura da string que está sendo analisada. Desta forma, você pode verificar se há duas condições na mesma expressão.

Por exemplo, para verificar se uma string contém pelo menos um caracter `"a"` e um caracter `"b"`:

```
^(?=.*a).*b
```

#### Expressão regular

```
^[^ab]*+(?=(?:[^b]*b){2})(?:[^a]*a){2}[^a]*$
```

[<kbd>Exemplo online</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/mrWvpJ/1/)

**Significado**

- `^[^ab]*+` - Caracteres opcionais que não são `a` nem `b` no início da string.
- `(?=(?:[^b]*b){2})` - Lookahead para verificar se há duas `b`, mais não avança na leitura da string.
- `(?:[^a]*a){2}[^a]*$` - Casa exatamente dois caracteres `a` até o final da string, mas não mais que dois.

#### Código

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = "^[^ab]*+(?=(?:[^b]*b){2})(?:[^a]*a){2}[^a]*$";

String[] exemplos = new String[] { 
    "---aabb+++", "---bbaa+++", "---abab+++", "---baba+++",
    "---babba++", "---bbbbbaa", "ababbb++++", "ccabcab+++",
    "----bcdbaa", "-ababd++++", "bbbaabbbbb", "bbbabbbbbb",
    "bbbaaabbbb", "baaaaaaaaa", "abbbbbbbbb", "ccacbcacbc"
};


final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for (String palavra : exemplos) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(palavra);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(palavra + " ✔️");
    } else {
        System.out.println(palavra + " ✖️️");
    }
}
```

**Resultado**

```
---aabb+++ ✔️
---bbaa+++ ✔️
---abab+++ ✔️
---baba+++ ✔️
---babba++ ✔️
---bbbbbaa ✔️
ababbb++++ ✔️
ccabcab+++ ✔️
----bcdbaa ✔️
-ababd++++ ✔️
bbbaabbbbb ✔️
bbbabbbbbb ✖️️
bbbaaabbbb ✖️️
baaaaaaaaa ✖️️
abbbbbbbbb ✖️️
ccacbcacbc ✔️
```

[<kbd>Exemplo online</kbd>](http://ideone.com/WA9Ib5)

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=^[.[^a]]*?a[.[^a]]*?a[.[^a]]*?$)^.*?b.*?b.*$");
//Use o find ou invés de matches
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("abdbbbabd").find());    //true
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("abdbbbbd").find());     //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente o padrão `^((.*[^a])?[a]{2}[b]{2,}.*)$`.
Explicação:
- O `^` no começo e o `$` no fim da força o reconhecimento completo da string.
- O padrão `(.*[^a])` evita o agrupamento de mais de dois `a`, e o `?` permite que o `[a]{2}[b]{2,}` seja no começo da string.
- O padrão `[a]{2}[b]{2,}` faz o reconhecimento desejado.
- O padrão `.*` no final completa a string.

Answer (score -1):

Sugiro a seguinte expressão regular:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(aa|bb)");
```

Veja o teste [online](https://regex101.com/r/omfJAQ/1).

Comment: Essa expressão não funcionou para o exercício, pois essa regex só valida a presença de "aa" ou "bb", e preciso validar palavras que tenham exatamente dois a em qualquer lugar da palavra e 2 ou mais b em qualquer lugar da palavra também

Comment: Tentei a seguinte regex "( a { 2 } | b { 2 , } )" mas não validou a palavra "babab"